# Pandas: New Date Variable From Datetime Variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset with a datetime variable `"CHECKIN_DATE_TIME"` and would like to create a new variable that is just the date sans the time. The `"CHECKIN_DATE_TIME"` is formatted as such `2020-02-01 11:13:17.000`. I want the new variable to be formatted like `2020-02-01`.

I'm referencing the following for help https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime but when I write my code, I'm getting attribute errors: `"Traceback(most recent call last)"` and `"DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strptime'"`

```
import datetime
NOTES_TAT=NOTES_TAT.strptime(CHECKIN_DATE_TIME,"%d %B, %Y")
```

Comment: What is the type of `NOTES_TAT`? Seems a pandas dataframe? give an example of this dataframe (say NOTES_TAT.head())

Answer (score 2):

You are using pandas dataframe. Try,

```
NOTES_TAT['CHECKIN_DATE_TIME'].dt.strftime('%d %B, %Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `datetime` wrapper via the `.dt` DataFrame accessor.  To get just the date, use the `.date` property at the end.

#### Example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Build a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'checkin': '2020-02-01 11:13:17.000'}, index=[0])
df['checkin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkin'])

# Create the date column using the `date` property.
df['date'] = df['checkin'].dt.date
# For a formatted date:
df['date'] = df['checkin'].dt.strftime('%d %B, %Y')
```

#### Output 1:

```
              checkin        date
0 2020-02-01 11:13:17  2020-02-01
```

#### Output 2:

```
              checkin               date
0 2020-02-01 11:13:17  01 February, 2020
```

Comment: Thanks @S3DEV So I'm still getting the same error when I run: df['date'] = df['checkin'].dt.strftime('%d %B, %Y'). The datatype for Checkin_date_time is 'object'. Do I need to change the datatype for Checkin_date_time?

Comment: Disregard, i reformatted the Checkin_date_time variable to datetime using this code:NOTES_TAT_v1['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(NOTES_TAT_v1['CHECKIN_DATE_TIME'], infer_datetime_format=True)